# Avoid multiple static classes with a single, different property

Tags: c#, .net, logging, static

My application consists of multiple, separate assemblies. Following a internal convention, every assembly defines an id used for logging.

Currently, there is a basic class called `CoreLog` which provides basic functionality like `Write`.  One of the parameters is the `Id`  I mentioned earlier.

Usually, every assembly then defines a class called `Log`, which simply calls the function from `CoreLog` **and** provides the unique id of the assembly.

That way we can simply stick to using `Log.Write` throughout the code.

That works well, except for the fact that I'll have to do that initially for every new assembly. And, if something changes, I have to adjust a numerous of files as well.

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: The way you're doing it now is probably the fastest solution. You provide the ID directly as an argument to the logging method. Using some comprehensive logic to determine the metadata of the caller (via `StackTrace`, `Assembly.GetCallingAssemby`, etc) will be definitely slower. The logging must be as fast as possible, especially if you log a lot.

Comment: @dymanoid I agree reflection is much slower (and unwinding the stack is _very_ slow), but I'll note you also shouldn't be logging on the hot path anyway.  It should be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
public static class SomeLogger
{
    public static void Write([CallerMemberName] string caller = string.Empty, string message)
    {
         //caller will be automatically populated
    }
}
```

You can also use `[CallerFilePath]` and `[CallerLineNumber]` if you'd like.

Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information).

If you need more information than those attributes provide you can just grab the [caller's assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly?view=netstandard-2.1):

```
public static class SomeLogger
{
    public static void Write(string message)
    {
         var callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
         //Grab whatever you need from callingAssembly and output it
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already using that feature, but the -assemblyID- is not equal to the method that called the function. It is defined manually.

Comment: @Shawn Then I'd use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`.  Does that work for you?  Its return type is `Assembly` and you can pick whatever information you need about the calling assembly.